# disk1s1 device is write locked

Tags: macos, imac, startup

I can not boot my iMac (20" Mid 2007) running OS X 10.7.5

When I am in Single User Mode I can use `fsck` and when trying `ti sbin/mount -uw /` it says device is write locked. I am really stuck.
I wanted to upgrade to El Capitan also I can not see any startup disk

Comment: We need to know the precise model, before we can decide whether the answer below is even vaguely relevant.

Comment: Daniil Manokhin you needed to know

Comment: Hi
This is the serial number of my Old Imac 20 inch and running OS X 10.7.5. 
VM802ZA3X86. I was trying to upgrade to El Capitan and now when I try to restart on the single user mode fsck is going well but mount -uw / give error disk1s1 device is write locked. Please advise

Comment: That would appear to make it this Mac, a 2007 model which cannot use Internet Recovery - https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-2-duo-2.4-20-inch-aluminum-specs.html

Comment: There seems to be a big jump between the upgrade to El Cap and attempting to run a command in Single User Mode.  Can you elaborate on the details here?  Also, what command is `ti sbin/mount`?  That's not a valid command.

Comment: Im having an identical problem. did you ever figure this out? please let me know if you did

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> 1. Restart the computer. Immediately after the chime hold down the (Command-Option-R) keys until a globe appears.
> 2. The Utility Menu will appear in from 5-20 minutes. Be patient.
> 3. Select Disk Utility and click on the Continue button.
> 4. When Disk Utility loads select the drive (usually, the out-dented entry) from the side list.
> 5. Click on the Erase tab in Disk Utility's main window. A panel will drop down.
> 6. Set the partition scheme to GUID.
> 7. Set the Format type to APFS (SSDs only) or Mac OS Extended (Journaled.)
> 8. Click on the Apply button, then click on the Done button when it activates.
> 9. Quit Disk Utility and return to the Utility Menu.
> 10. Select Reinstall OS X and click on the Continue button.

([Source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8315488?answerId=33144333022#33144333022))

Comment: What makes you think internet recovery mode works on a machine running 10.7? This would work well on very new firmware Macs. Does a single one of them support 10.7? Are you just googling things and seeing what sticks? Not trying to be mean, but you will waste peoples time if you don’t know how to check an answer. -1

Comment: @bmike see https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201314

Comment: I’m well acquainted with that article. Do you understand which models support that feature?

Comment: Hi Daniil Manokhin
This is the serial number of my Old Imac 20 inch and running OS X 10.7.5. 
VM802ZA3X86. I was trying to upgrade to El Capitan and now when I try to restart on the single user mode fsck is going well but mount -uw / give error disk1s1 device is write locked. Please advise
Germain